The setItem runs every time after refresh
In the useEffect hook the setItems runs every time when the page is refreshed and sets the same items again. Can t=you help me with this, please.
  useEffect(() => {
    if (inputArr.length > 0) {
      window.localStorage.setItem("inputArr", JSON.stringify(inputArr));
      console.log("set", inputArr);
    }
  }, [inputArr]);


Here you are in a useEffect hook, not a useState hook.
That's why setItem is triggered every page refreshing at first, and it will be triggered again if [inputArr] is changed.

I am sorry, I wanted to write useEffect.

Hi, Page refresh in SPA - Single Page Application needs to be reviewed, please see a post here : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57577979/refresh-a-page-in-a-single-page-application
